# $(A \to B) \to (\lnot A \lor B)$ intutionistically valid?

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, intuitionistic-logic

Can anybody explain if the formula $(A \to B) \to (\lnot A \lor B)$ is intuitionistically valid? If I understood the logic right, it is not but I am not sure, because a am not able to provide a counter example. :-(

Comment: Are you familiar with Kripke models?

Comment: For instance, $P \rightarrow P$ is always true but intuitionistically, $\lnot P \vee P$ is not a valid conclusion.

Comment: @HanulJeon just a little bit.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Sry, but I don't see the hint in your answer. I know that in Intuitionistic Logic ¬P∨P is not valid, but in my example I have ¬A∨B in conclusion. Pleas can you give me some further explanaition?

Comment: Ah, now I got it. That was a hint how to create a counter example. :-)